# Language Server in docker container

Tags: docker, neovim

I'm not sure if the title suites my question that well but I couldn't come up with a better one.

As I'm running Arch Linux but develop software (in C++) which has to run on Debian and Ubuntu I'm currently on the following setup. I have neovim (because I really like it) with [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe) and [this setup](https://github.com/AlexandreCarlton/ycmd-docker) to run the ycm-server within the Docker (which runs Debian).

Now I would like to give [coc.nvmim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) together with [clangd](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clangd/) or [ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls) a try as it seems to give a better user experience than [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe). I'm now wondering if it is possible to run [clangd](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clangd/) or [ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls) on the server and let [coc.nvmim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) connect to it without problems. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything with Google and therefore I'm asking the StackOverflow community.

Comment: Have you found a solution or any experience to share? I'd like to setup something similar.

Comment: So far I'm still using ccls running on my Arch Linux. This way, going back and forth in my code does work, but I don't have access to libraries api, e.g. OpenCV. Therefore, I tend to have the api documentation open in my browser and look up the functions/methods there.